# Is there a limit on the number of filters that can be passed to DynamoDB query

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, opensearch, amazon-cloudsearch

I’d like to search for something like

Field “Id” has a value in [Long list of IDs]

This long list of Ids can hit over 1000 Ids.

should I expect a problem with that? Is there a limit on how long the query can be?

I am looking at cloudsearch and it seems to have  a limit of 1024 clauses and wondering if it should just be done from DynamoDB if there are no limits on it.

At that point, I guess I should also ask if Elastic search/Open search has such limits,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can review the various DynamoDB limits at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html. Here's two that will impact you:

> The maximum length of any expression string is 4 KB.

> The maximum number of operands for the IN comparator is 100.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch has a limit on max clause a query can have as explained in the [search settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html#search-settings), but if you are using it only to filter the data, as you mentioned in your question, than you can simply use the [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) where you can send a long list of ids to filter on, this is also advised by Elasticsearch in the same document search settings.

Answer (score 1):

> Field “Id” has a value in [Long list of IDs]
> This long list of Ids can hit over 1000 Ids.

Is Id your primary key?
If so, no because in dynamo you can do `batchGet` operation on passing the Ids and for 1000 you will have to do 10 concurrent/sequential calls to dynamo.

if it's not a primary key, i.e. a secondary index then you will have to do 1000 concurrent `query` operation to check the presence of the key.